# How to Solve Remove Repeat Position in listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview

[image]

First time 16 item load in the listview.
I need only 2 item selected (red color button).
But when I scroll the listview all item after i showing wrong selected 11 item.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

            v = convertView;
            holder = new PlanetHolder();
            if (convertView == null)
            {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

                holder.btn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn1);

                holder.displayname = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt);

                if(selectedarray.get(position).equals("1"))
                {
                    holder.btn.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);
                    holder.btn.setClickable(false);

                }
                holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {

                    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
               v.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
                Log.d("else_position", "else_position= "+position);
            holder = (PlanetHolder) v.getTag();
            ItemList p = planetList.get(position);
            holder.displayname.setText(p.getU_name());

            return v;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write else part also.

```
if (selectedarray.get(position).equals("1")) {
            holder.btn.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);
            holder.btn.setClickable(false);
        } else {
            holder.btn.setBackgroundColor(R.color.white);
            holder.btn.setClickable(true);
        }
```

Comment: first time load true red button but i scroller listview after i showing 11 item red button.i not need 11 item red button.

Comment: use viewholder in your adapter

Answer (score 0):

First

```
 if (selectedarray.get(position).equals("1")) {
                holder.btn.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);
                holder.btn.setClickable(false);
            } else {
                holder.btn.setBackgroundColor(R.color.white);
                holder.btn.setClickable(true);
            }
```

Second dont keep it under `if (convertView == null)` or in `else` part

keep it after if and else block

see here

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

                v = convertView;
                holder = new PlanetHolder();
                if (convertView == null)
                {

                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

                    holder.btn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn1);

                    holder.displayname = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt);


                   v.setTag(holder);
                }
                else
                 {
                   Log.d("else_position", "else_position= "+position);
                   holder = (PlanetHolder) v.getTag();
                 }

                ItemList p = planetList.get(position);
                holder.displayname.setText(p.getU_name());

                  if(selectedarray.get(position).equals("1"))
                    {
                        holder.btn.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);
                        holder.btn.setClickable(false);

                    }
                    holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                    {

                        @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                    });

                return v;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem.

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

                v = convertView;
                holder = new PlanetHolder();
                if (convertView == null)
                {

                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

                    holder.btn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn1);

                    holder.displayname = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt);

                    if(selectedarray.get(position).equals("1"))
                    {
                        holder.btn.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);
                        holder.btn.setClickable(false);

                    }
                    holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                    {

                        @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                    });
                   v.setTag(holder);
                }
                else
                    Log.d("else_position", "else_position= "+position);
                holder = (PlanetHolder) v.getTag();
                ItemList p = planetList.get(position);
                holder.displayname.setText(p.getU_name());
                if(selectedarray.get(position).equals("1"))
                    {
                        holder.btn.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);
                        holder.btn.setClickable(false);

                    }
               else
               {
                        holder.btn.setBackgroundColor(R.color.white);
                        holder.btn.setClickable(true);
                }
                return v;
            }
```